# Precautions before changing air filter

Tags: air-intake, air-filter, intake-manifold

I am using Chevrolet Sail-Uva Diesel 2013 model(India). I am about to change my air filter. Is there any cleaning process before changing air filter in cars? Anybody have great tips can improve this post better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 clean around filter box

2 open filter box and remove old filter - dispose of it correctly

3  clean inside the filter box as necessary and fit cleaned or new filter

4 close filter box - make sure lid is seated correctly.

Comment: I can see some leafs inside the filter box. So i am little bit confused. The seating is correctly. Then how its come.

Comment: They came through the inlet pipe feeding the air box....

Comment: What should be the frequency of changing air/oil/diesel filters?

Comment: That is a new question and should be posted as such. Have you looked for any manuals or information for your vehicle?

Comment: Ha ha.. I didn't check any manuals. I just wanna get add-on info from experts like you.

Comment: That is an appalling attitude, for several reasons, not the least of which is that I dont have a copy of the manual for your vehicle. Please read the info on this site about how to ask questions. Your response Ha ha.. I didn't check any manuals is not very polite either.